# Need to access search keyword in a custom rendering controller in SXA

Tags: sxa, content-search, azure-search

We are using SXA 1.8 with Sitecore 9. And, we have the requirement to access the search keyword passed in the search-box in one of the custom-renderings. But unfortunately, SXA is appending the search keyword in URL hash instead of Query-string. So, its difficult to access the search term in the controller code. I found it is not possible to change from Hash to Query-string as per this link [Changing hash to query string](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9291/changing-hash-to-query-string).

So, I just want to know is there any better way to access the search term in custom controller. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SXA is storing the search phrase in hash only on the front-end. This param is later on processed in `component-search-service.js` and base on the rest of things from the hash and some default settings of the renderings we are building the URL. It contains the following query parameters:

[image]

As you see the `q` is there and you can use it.